# IBM Websphere Liberty profile: JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15"

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, java-websocket

I just deployed a hello world kinda application on IBM WebShphere Liberty profile. The deployment was successful but I'm getting error when accessing the application. The application was bascically Java WebSocket implementation using Project Tyrus.

```
Aug 12, 2015 10:11:02 AM SessionContextRegistryImpl getSessionContext
INFO: SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/WSRITyrus
Aug 12, 2015 10:11:02 AM com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspOptions populateOptions
INFO: JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15".
```

Any thought?

Comment: These are INFO messages not errors. What kind of error do you see while accessing the application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes thoese are INFO message. It looks when I did the Websocket call I got those messages and do not reach to the server.

Comment: Wy dont you use websockets provided with Liberty instead of third party? You will find some working examples of web sockets apps for Liberty on [wasdev.net](http://wasdev.net)

Comment: You'll need to share a more concrete observation of what happened when you accessed the server.